# TINYMCE - Path to upload images folder with jbimages plugin doesn't work

Tags: php, tinymce-4

I have a problem to configure the path for uploading images inside tinymce 4.0 using the plugin jbimages.

Into file config.php of the plugin i have

```
$config['img_path'] = 'test/admin/uploads'; // Relative to domain name
$config['upload_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $config['img_path']; // Physical     path. [Usually works fine like this]
```

Doesn't work.
Checking path with $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] i have

```
/web/htdocs/www.example.com/home/
```

So the full path is:

```
/web/htdocs/www.example.com/home/test/admin/uploads
```

What i want is

```
http://www.example.com/test/admin/uploads
```

and if i try to set it into  $config['img_path'] as a absolute path doesn't work as well

```
    $config['img_path'] = 'http://www.example.com/test/admin/uploads'; // Relative to domain name
$config['upload_path'] = $config['img_path'];
```

what can i do??
thanks

Answer (score 0):

try a beginning slash in the image path

```
$config['img_path'] = '/test/admin/uploads'; // Relative to domain name
```